# Vectorizing fortran array operation

Tags: performance, compilation, fortran, vectorization, gfortran

I am looking into optimizing some fortran code and one kind of optimization that came to mind is using vector instructions. Of course the compiler vectorizes a lot of operations when compiling with -O3 (I am using gfortran compiler). Naturally it misses some vectorization opportunities that seem possible for example this line of code:

```
p%glnrho(:,i)=p%rho1*p%grho(:,i)
```

Here p is declared type and the arrays are real arrays of dimension (nx,3),(nx),(nx,3) respectively.

With -fopt-info-vec-missed I get the following explanation:
missed:

```
 not vectorized: complicated access pattern.
```

There are multiple of these kinds of array operations so I am thinking that does there exist a simple hint that I can give the compiler that would work in this case that I could use in multiple places. Or possibly some other approach that wouldn't require too much code modification.

Apologies if the question isn't explained well enough or too specific to my situation. I am not the most familiar how the compiler translates fortran array operations to vector instructions so any answers would be appreciated :)

What have I tried:

Tried to compile with optimizations turned on i.e. -O3 and see how well the compiler translates array operations to vector instructions. The compiler seems to miss some opportunities that don't seem that complex

Comment: How are the entities in that line of code declared? Where do they come from?

Comment: What are `%lnrho` and `%grho`? Which types? Fixed size arrays? Allocatable arrays? Pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I would try first an `associate` construct to hopefully simplify what the compiler sees:

```
ASSOCIATE( a => p%glnrho(:,i), b => p%rho1*p%grho(:,i) )
    a(:) = b(:)
END ASSOCIATE
```

To answer a possible objection, associate names are not pointers, despite the similar notation.

EDIT: if it's still not optimizing, just try `a = b` as mentioned by @VladimirFГероямслава in the comments.

Comment: I doubt it will help but if you do this, do just `a = b` https://stevelionel.com/drfortran/2008/03/31/doctor-it-hurts-when-i-do-this/

Comment: Old habit to always specify (at least when it doesn't hurt) the `(:)` in order to make clear this is an array syntx

Comment: That is exactly what Steven mentions in that blog post *"with the (:) alerting the reader that the variable is an array (sort of like the Dave Barry joke that an apostrophe serves to warn you that the letter “s” is coming up in grocery store signs.)"*

Comment: This link was not here when I commented... While I agree with the general idea expressed by Steve and I'm aware of all of this, I still have a preference for `a(:)` when it is supposed to give the same result than `a`.  I know that some years ago this could hurt the optimization, but in 2023 I consider that a compiler that would be unable to optimize that would not be trustable for HPC.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly it didn't solve the problem and I get: missed: statement clobbers memory. I guess there isn't a general way to get the compiler to do vector instructions and I should spend my energy on the critical loops.

Comment: With further investigation I found out that even though the line in code is in -fopt-vectorization-missed it is also in -fopt-info-vect-optimized which is somewhat strange. I guess it is since there might be multiple possible vectorization opportunities on the same line or it uses a backup if it can't perform some kind of optimal vectorization